# Why is showes error processing package mysql-server-8.0 (--configure)?

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu

I'm new at PHP Laravel and I'm setting up Laravel by downloading the packages and Xampp in Lubuntu. When I download mysql by runing the command:  `sudo apt install mysql-server` it shows me an error:

```
^[ORdpkg: error processing package mysql-server-8.0 (--configure):
 installed mysql-server-8.0 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-8.0; however:
  Package mysql-server-8.0 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                             Processing triggers for systemd (245.4-4ubuntu3.11) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-8.0
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have also tried to remove the mysql, upgrade and update sudo apt install and to install it again but still shows the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope to help you

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get purge 'mysql*'
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get install mysql-server-8.0
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: It would make a little more sense to OP if you explain how you came to such an answer.

Comment: I'm sure it's working, the idea is to educate OP on why you did what you did.

Comment: I suggest to you lean more about Linux commands.

Comment: I think you're missing the point here. The idea here is to help, educate and point to resources. Everyone can follow someone else's steps, but it makes more sense to explain it to others so they know how to debug any similar issue in the future.

Comment: This answer left out a very important step - you MUST reboot the Linux machine after purging mysql or else the same error will persist.